# IBM U2 (UniVerse 10.2) - Create Schema - How

Tags: permissions, u2, universe, multivalue-database

We have a traditional UV account. Data files in one directory, application programs & subroutines in another directory. Our latest projects is implementing JDBC and in order to fully access the subroutines from java, I belive I need to create a schema on the existing uv account.

How can I do this? I tried logging in as uvadm and create a schema. Get the following error:

> CREATE SCHEMA TEST;
>   UniVerse/SQL: "uvadm" is not an SQL user.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

They're both admin, per the docs, but a UniVerse Admin is simply someone who has r/w perms on the underlying files used in creation (uvadm and/or root).

> Who Is a UniVerse Administrator?
>
> To
> perform most administration tasks, you
> must be logged on as a UniVerse
> Administrator. On UNIX systems,
> UniVerse administrators must log on as
> root or as uvadm. On Windows systems,
> UniVerse administrators must log on as
> a member of the Administrators group.
> You can then use UniVerse Admin and
> UniVerse administration commands to
> perform UniVerse administration.

However, a *UniVerse SQL* *admin* is the person who has read/write permissions on the *CATALOG*. If you can't create a catalog it is probably because you don't have r/w perms on the directory you're in, because the catalog is just a file.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed UniVerse, who did you say the owner of uvsql is - uvadm or root?  The only way I know to resolve this problem is to go through a reinstallation to allow answer uvadm so all the files within SQL will be setup and cataloged properly.